# Не работает navbar-toggle

Tags: bootstrap, laravel

Работаю на фреймверке laravel 5 и подключил так же bootstrap-3, но не срабатывает navbar-toggle...при уменьшении экрана появляется эта кнопка,но при нажатии ничего не происходит...в проекте bootstrap-3 этот код работает, подскажите в чем причина?
П.С.: bootstrap 3 подключил нормально, все работает а вот navbar-toggle не хочет....

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>NAME</h1>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rm">
                        <span class="sr-only">Open navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="rm">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">type 1</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">type 2</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">type 2</a> </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="image/en.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы bootstrap.js подключили ?

Comment: спасибо огромное, я его то подключил, но путь не изменил....js внизу кода подключается в шапке link  поизменял, а внизу забыл!еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

внизу кода добавить эти строки:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7 /js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```